# Flutter - TabBar inside Column

Tags: flutter

I have a `Column` with an Image and below it a `DefaultTabController`. The TabBar basically does not display the tabs, but the children of the `TabBarView` are displayed.

That's the **error**:

> Null check operator used on a null value The relevant error-causing
> widget was
> TabBar  lib/…/screens/specific_launch.dart:132 The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
> RenderCustomPaint#83c8d relayoutBoundary=up10 RenderObject:
> RenderCustomPaint#83c8d relayoutBoundary=up10
> parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=336.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> size: Size(336.0, 100000.0)
> child: RenderErrorBox#daadf NEEDS-PAINT
> parentData:  (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=336.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> size: Size(336.0, 100000.0)

That's the **code**:

```
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'Launch',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share_outlined), onPressed: () {})
      ],
    ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: getHeight(context) / 30.0,
          left: getWidth(context) / 30.0,
          right: getWidth(context) / 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // ...first child


          SizedBox(
            width: getWidth(context),
            height: getHeight(context),
            child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 3,
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          text: 'State',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Mission',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Rocket',
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  body: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Tab 1',
                      ),
                      Text('Tab 2'),
                      Text('Tab 3')
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

That's the result I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Results]

Comment: What's your reason for nesting `Scaffold` widgets?

Comment: I saw the documentation for the DefaultTabController, and there should be a Scaffold with an AppBar and a body

Comment: Remove Sizedbox and Try to wrap DefaultTabController with an Expanded widget, if OutOfBoundary causes the issue.

Comment: Nope, still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you want to use the `DefaultTabController` widget then you must start your widget tree with the `DefaultTabController` widget and then add your `Scaffold`. After that I used only one `Scaffold` and added rest of part with the help of `Expanded` widget

Here is [output image](http://prntscr.com/xhziuu)

```
class SelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _selectionScreen();
  }
}
class _selectionScreen extends State<SelectionScreen>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Launch',),
            actions: [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share_outlined), onPressed: () {})],
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network("https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Aaj.png", height: 150,),
              Container(
                height: 70,
                child: AppBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("New Titile"),
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: 'State',),
                      Tab(text: 'Mission',),
                      Tab(text: 'Rocket',)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Text('Tab 1',),
                    Text('Tab 2'),
                    Text('Tab 3')
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me the same error and the tabs are still not displayed

Comment: @Arfmann i thik first you need to flutter clean and then try with this code because it gives output wait ill add screenshot

Comment: @Arfmann please recheck my updataed answer

Comment: That's pretty strange, it doesn't works for me. That's my full code https://pastebin.com/YbDbxd2h

Comment: @Arfmann please add what error you are getting

Comment: @Arfmann `launchesObject` please share this one also so ill debug it at my end

Comment: The error is the same as the question. launchesObject is a global variable to store an API result, but it doesn't affect the TabBar. By the way, I've tried removing the TabBar() from the AppBar and it works: the AppBar is correctly displayed. So the problem is the TabBar() widget, because it causes the error and the entire AppBar() disappear

Comment: not sure about this because this is working at my end so

Comment: I've just tried with a TabBar() directly inside the Scaffold's AppBar() and it still gives me the same error. At this point, I believe is not a problem related with my code, otherwise it should works with the test I did

Comment: @Arfmann Okay not sure then . You can open same issue on github and add this link maybe github developers help you

Comment: Even whit a whole new screen is the same. Just a controller, scaffold and appbar and still gives me the same error: it seems is not my code to be wrong

Comment: hehe, now I'm confused :) :). Once you solved this issue then please let us know why the issue persists Thank you

Comment: Just tried wrapping it inside a MaterialApp() and it now works. I'm so confused too. The root of the entire app is inside the MaterialApp, so why should i put another MaterialApp for using a TabBar? That's so strange (and broken)

Comment: Ohhh shut, Exactly bro may be your `MaterialApp` is missing in the root file `main.dart` so the issue occurred. Main.dart file is right at my end so this issue not occurred me.

Comment: Well expected UI you got from answer if yes then kindly please do upvote and true mark Thank you and if no still thank you @Arfmann

Comment: the MaterialApp is already in the root file, but I still have to wrap it inside the other file. I'll do a research about that, pheraps the Navigator is removing it or something. Anyway, at this points your answer is correct, thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227722/discussion-between-arfmann-and-shubham-narkhede).